# Reactor 3 Emitter/Subscriber paralllel

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

i'm new in Reactive programming and have a lot of questions.
I think it is not a lack of examples or documentation it is just my understanding is wrong.

I'm trying to emulate slow subscriber;

Here is the code example

```
Flux.create(sink -> {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleep for " + MILLIS);
            Thread.sleep(MILLIS);
            int it = i++;
            System.out.println("Back to work, iterator " + it);
            sink.next(it);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
.subscribe(x -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Value: " + x + ", Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
        Thread.sleep(MILLIS + 4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

System out is

```
Sleep for 1000
Back to work, iterator 0
Value: 0, Thread: Thread[elastic-2,5,main]
Sleep for 1000
Back to work, iterator 1
Value: 1, Thread: Thread[elastic-2,5,main]
Sleep for 1000
Back to work, iterator 2
Value: 2, Thread: Thread[elastic-2,5,main]
```

I thought if subscriber is slow, i should see more threads due to `Schedulers.elastic()`

Also i tried to make `publishOn()` and it seems like i make it async, but still couldn't handle result in several threads.

Thanks for comments and answers.

Comment: If you want to emulate slow subscriber you should do the opposite - instead of emitting one item with a delay you should create make lots of those created without any delay

Comment: @pixel that is fair, but what if i'm working with blocking code, for example reading from queue?

Comment: Then it means that your publisher is slow (emits few items) and subscriber just waits   for events. Thus you don't need many subscribers.

Comment: @pixel but yeah i think i understand. But what if subscriber is slower than emitter? You could see it from code, it is working as blocking code with 1 working Thread.

Comment: When subscriber is slower than emiter then you can take advantage of back-pressure. There is a good  article on that: https://www.e4developer.com/2018/04/28/springs-webflux-reactor-parallelism-and-backpressure/ But still - your code does not reflect such case :)

Comment: Never use Thread.sleep when doing reactive programming. You are putting the event loop to sleep.

Comment: Of course it is just an example, btw subscriber could have sleep AFAIK.

Comment: Nothing in your example runs in parallel. More importantly you have only one subscriber. Having several threads doesn't make much sense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run in diferent threads you need to use .parallel() like this and the emit will be don in different thread

```
Flux.create(sink -> {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleep for " + MILLIS);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                int it = i++;
                System.out.println("Back to work, iterator " + it);
                sink.next("a");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    })

            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())

            .subscribe(x -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Value: " + x + ", Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
                    Thread.sleep(100 + 4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
    ;
}
```

Comment: That is interesting but i totally don't understand what is going on :) In my head whe should see something like we emitting in some Mills, and consuming it with delay, in parallel threads so we should first emit several values, then consume.

Comment: @VIQ you are subscribing in elastic but you should know that you subscribe only one time in your stream and your stream will find a free thread in elastic pool so all stream will run in a single elastic thread so you are waiting for delay. in my case im separating every element in new parallel  stream that gets new thread in elastic pool